# Ruby on Rails: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good afternoon.
I'm trying Ruby on Rails, so I'm doing the getting started page tutorial.
The problem comes when I did the articles validations and trying to go to the articles list.

The error is in the model, but I can't find it, so I need some help.
The model code where Rails throws the error:

```rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence :true, length: {minimum: 5}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to move the colon before **true**, it should be `presence: true` instead of `presence :true`

Comment: It worked! I didn't know to see that fail. A lot of thanks :D